Kubernetes dynamic volume provisioning problem
I am trying to get the dynamic volume provisioning to work with my pods. but it looks like there is a problem like pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims in the pending status pod in my cluster. I have read some other posts about this problem but no luck to solve this problem. The way I did it, is like:
I created a StoragClass like:
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer   

and then I created two PersistentVolum like:
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-01
  labels:
    type: pd-ssd
spec:
  storageClassName: fast
  capacity:
    storage: 300Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/path/to/somelocaldirectory"


kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-02
  labels:
    type: pd-ssd
spec:
  storageClassName: fast
  capacity:
    storage: 300Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/path/to/somelocaldirectory"

Then in the postgres pod I put :
volumes:
  - name: postgres-conf
    configMap:
      name: confpostgres
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: postgresdata
  spec:
    accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
    storageClassName: fast
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 300Mi

As I said there is a problem like pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims in the postgres pod.
Any help?

You shouldn't usually need to manually create PersistentVolume objects.  You shouldn't need StorageClasses in most cases either; if you do, the administrator who set up the cluster should create it, and they can tell you what an appropriate storageClassName is.

I removed storageClassName from the postgres pod, but still have the same error. If I do not create the pv manually, I have also the same problem.

The cluster created by kubeadm.

That sounds like a problem with the persistent volume provisioner in your cluster, and you'll have to ask a local sysadmin to help you.  It is not particularly a programming problem.
